# Opencv 3.0 contrib Java

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to use the BackgroundSubtractorMOG from the opencv_contrib but seems like some modules are no ready for Java.
Are all extras modules available for Java?
am I missing an step? I follow this

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/

All the rest seems to be working good.
All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! I am successfully build the OpenCV with extra modules and created the Jar file for Java, which I tested it was working well, but I did not see any new things in this Jar file, I mean that where the contrib code for Java, this Jar file is almost the same as the Jar file which came whit OpenCV download file. If you understand me the question, please tell me that I did wrong some where in building Jar file Or it is like this? Thank you very much. Note: I have included everything while build Jar file